# How to record mp4 file using AVCaptureSession?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, avcapturesession, avcapturemoviefileoutput

I am  recording `.mov` using `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` with `AVCaptureSession`. I want to record `.mp4` file, i guess it is not possible with `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`, Any idea how to record `.mp4` file?

Edit:
I have googled and found, there is a way `AVAssetWriter`, however it is not simple as `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`?

thanks

Comment: hey i did task of making video from images using AVAssetWriter, and the outPut is in .mp4 format..

Comment: Ya I too downloaded a sample project related to that, Is there any simple way like AVCaptureMovieFileOutput. It no needs any extra work. If no other way then I have to follow that one only :)

Comment: i don't have any idea regard this right now...will update u whenever i will get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one more way to record mp4 file, Actually its not recording, after recording with .mov we can convert that into mp4 file if we want. It is not the exact answer for the question, it may helps someone.

Comment: Are you saying that we cannot save mp4 files  using AVCaptureSession?